# How to fix JavaScript heap out of memory on multipart.Parse() for azure function api

Tags: node.js, azure-functions, multipartform-data

Recently I've been using an azure function api to upload video files from the front end to my azure blob storage backend. I send the file info using formData and then parse that using multipart.Parse().

The issue is, on certain files (usually ones that are larger in size), exactly when the program tries to run "multipart.Parse(bufferBody, boundary)" the azure function throws this error:

> FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory.

The strange thing is, the file that I am uploading is only 52.1 MB.

Below is my code for the azure function:
`

```
const {BlobServiceClient} = require('@azure/storage-blob');
var multipart=require("parse-multipart");
const AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING = process.env["AZURE_VIDEO_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING"];
const fs = require("fs");


module.exports=async function(context, req){
        var boundary=multipart.getBoundary(req.headers['content-type']);
        const memory = process.memoryUsage();
        var bufferBody= Buffer.from(req.body)
        fs.writeFileSync("C:/home/site/wwwroot/heapLimit.txt", stats['heap_size_limit'].toString());
       fs.writeFileSync("C:/home/site/wwwroot/bufferBody.txt", bufferBody.toString());
             var parts = multipart.Parse(bufferBody, boundary);
                              
             const blobServiceClient = await BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString(AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING);
                                const container='feed-videos';
                                const containerClient= await blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(container);
                                const blobName=parts[0].filename;
                                const blockBlobClient=containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blobName);
                                const uploadBlobResponse = await blockBlobClient.upload(parts[0].data, parts[0].data.length);
                                context.res= {body: {name : parts[0].filename, type: parts[0].type, data:parts[0].data.length}}
                        
                                context.done()

   

}
```

`

I already tried using max-old-space size and printed out the heap statistics as below:
`C:\home\site\wwwroot\VideoUpload>node --max-old-space-size=10000 index.js

Heap Statistics are :
total_heap_size:22220800
used_heap_size:14019688
heap_size_limit:10536091648
does_zap_garbage:0

`

Running the api upload and tracking some data right before the call gives me this reading of the heap_size_limit and bodyBuffer file size:

- bufferBody.txt    11/29/2022, 5:39:12 PM  103969 KB
- heap_size_limit : 1660944384

Note that it seems the heap_size_limit change was not permanent, but even still, the size of the bufferBody is no where near the heap_size_limit, so I don't understand where the error is coming from. Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

P.s.
I believe I am using a consumption plan.

Answer (score 0):

the error states: Application is using more memory than is available on your system or the other reason you have a memory leak.

to debug this we have to find which address is causing the high memory usage, you can find out using a memory profile tool and if you still think it's not memory leak, then run your application with
`--max-old-space-size` flag to increase the maximum amount of memory that is available to your nodejs process. cheers